# Auto Reconnect Bluetooth Headphones in OS X

Tags: macos, mac, bluetooth

Snow Leopard:
How do I make my bluetooth stereo headphones automatically reconnect to my Mac (ready for me to hit Play in iTunes) when I resume it from sleep  or from off?

Answer (score 0):

Which OS-X version? I think that this is standard since Snow Leopard at least, so long as you have not powered down your headset.